# Richface library upgrade from 3.2 to 4.5

Tags: richfaces

I need to upgrade one of our application from Richface 3.2 to 4.5.

I have followed the guide here https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration

But it seems some of the packages has changed from 3.2 to 4.5
For example org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlToolBar has no more in 4.5.

Does anybody upgrade from 3.2 to 4.5? Please help.

Is there any documentation where I can find the complete list of package changed in 4.5.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The class you're looking for is `org.richfaces.component.UIToolbar`, I assume HTML* classes were renamed to UI*.

There isn't a guide for this as far as I know, but you can try checking the [javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/javadoc/) for similarly named classes.